can not unhide Library folder
Finder does not show me my folder ~/Library, although it is there (in the command line, I can do a ls -ld on this folder).
According to various sources - for instance here, I can make the folder visible by using the Go menu, and there the Home menu entry.
However, this also does not show my Library folder.
I can do from the command line a open ~/Library, and this does open a Finder window with this folder, but I would like to see this folder always from my home directory, in the same way as i.e. Documents or Pictures are shown.

Navigate to your Home folder in the Finder. Once there, from the View menu select Show View Options. At the bottom should be a check box Show Library Folder. Check this.

